# strange error message while using mutate and case_when to update a var

Tags: r

I have a df with 56 rows, and I want to update var `PAV" base on` tt`. It is very simple but I got very strange errors. Could anyone tell me what might be the reason?

```
df<-structure(list(tt = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                        "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                        "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                        "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), PAV = structure(c("2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                                                    "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
                                                                    "3", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                    "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
                                                                    "4", "4", "4", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
                                                                    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                                                    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                                                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
                                                                    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = c(56L, 
                                                                                                                                  2L))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 56L))

df<- df %>% 
mutate(PAV=case_when(tt=="Y"~PAV))
```

The error code is: `Error: Problem with` mutate()`column`PAV`. i` PAV = case_when(tt == "Y" ~ PAV)`. x` tt == "Y" ~ PAV `must be length 56 or one, not 112.`

Comment: Your `PAV` column is a matrix.  Do you want to keep that as matrix column?

Comment: I see now. I build PAV from another variable and unaware that I make it into matrix.  Is it a way to make it back as a variable? When I check `df`, it looks like it just has 2 variables. 

Comment: In addition, the logic is not clear.  When the 'tt' values are 'Y', you want to keep the PAV rows, and for those, `NA`?

Comment: Yes, just keep PAV value when tt=="Y"

Comment: Which PAV? PAV.1 or PAV.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column 'PAV' is a `matrix` column.  We may need to convert to two regular columns first and then loop `across` those columns to update the values

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  invoke(data.frame, .) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('PAV'), ~ case_when(tt %in% 'Y' ~ .x)))
```

Comment: If I do str(df) I get `'data.frame': 56 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ tt : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ PAV: chr [1:56, 1:2] "2" "2" "2" "2" ...` Where is the part with the matrix?

Comment: @TarJae It is the second column `chr [1:56, 1:2]` which is a matrix or you can check as `sapply(df, class)`

Comment: @Stataq is this applied on the nmatrix i.e. `PAVO` in your original data is a matrix

Comment: PAVO is not a matrix.

Comment: @Stataq `str_extract_all` returns all occurence of that pattern.  e.g. a single string will be broken down into multiple i.e. `str_extract_all('17ed898', "\\d+", simplify = TRUE)#
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,] "17" "898"`.  How do you want this result to be.  I would keep it as two columns as these are from the row element

Comment: @Stataq If you can update your post with your original `PAVO` column and what you expect as output, it may be easier to understand.  Maybe you want only the first set of digits?

Comment: Your comment above explains thing well enough. 